# Register Cydia tweak for push notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, jailbreak, cydia

The tweak I am developing requires registering for push notifications. I know how to do it with a normal application, but have no clue how to get it to work for a tweak. Would I have to somehow register through SpringBoard? Or perhaps register a system app? (Once I get the notification to the device, I can handle displaying it appropriately myself.) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would it be possible to install a full-blown **app** of your own, in addition to the **tweak**?  Then, the app could register for notifications in the normal way.  When the app gets the notification, it posts a custom notification that your tweak has subscribed for, essentially passing the notification content to your tweak, which then handles it.  You could hide the SpringBoard icon of the *app* so that it doesn't appear separately to the user.  Just brainstorming here ....

Comment: @Nate I doubt apple would be keen on accepting an app with the sole purpose of passing notifications to a jailbreak tweak. But if I don't go through apple then we are back to the original problem

Comment: Of course you wouldn't publish the app through the app store.  If you're considering building a **tweak**, then you've already decided to release your software another way.  What I'm suggesting is to release a "package" through Cydia that would contain one Mobile Substrate tweak, and one full-blown "app", bundled together.

Comment: @Nate even if I wrote a "full blown app" for Cydia, how would I register that for push notifications? Registering an App Store app for APNS requires signing certificates from apple.

Comment: *Enterprise distribution* does not require you to release the app through the App Store.  You didn't say you couldn't sign the app with a valid certificate.  If that's the case, you should add that caveat to the question.

Comment: @Nate I do have a valid dev account, but it seems like there must be an easier way to receive push notifications than writing another app in Xcode, signing a certificate for it, making my users install my tweak **and** it's companion app (not to mention the added difficulty of simply installing an enterprise app), then hiding the app from springboard. Plus doesn't it cost extra to register for an enterprise dev account? There must be some other way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there **must** be some other way.  Apple doesn't design their APIs to do things they don't want you to do, which everything involving *tweaks* would qualify as.  There's not two steps to install a tweak and an app.  You bundle them as one debian package, and Cydia installs them both together.  Users are unaware of the existence of the two distinct pieces.  Yes, it does cost extra for the Enterprise Account.  Still half the price of an iPhone, though.